# Why shouldn't I mix Spring and Java annotations?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In a recent code review I was advised against using `@Resource(name = "resourceName")` instead of the more verbose `@Autowired` `@Qualifier("resourceName")` as it is "bad to mix Spring and Java annotations". The reviewer could offer no reasoning to back this up.

Can anyone explain to me why it is frowned upon to mix Spring and Java annotations in this way?

Comment: There is probably no great reason behind it, its just when using spring magic is just better to go for everything that it offers as spring is going to manage stuff for you, and going to deal with stuff its way. Spring components are managed in a nice way, let's say if you think of having a big bucket of Lego, all needed parts are inside a Spring is just doing its stuff, Mixing it with other libraries can create developer confusion or program confusion in some cases.

Comment: It's just an opinion. One reason I could guess is to make a distinction between Spring and J2EE ecosystems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no great reason behind it.

Its just when using spring magic is just better to go for everything that it offers as spring is going to manage stuff for you, and going to deal with stuff its way.

Spring components are managed in a nice way, let's say if you think of having a big bucket of Lego, all needed parts are inside and Spring is just doing its stuff, Mixing it with other libraries can create developer confusion or program confusion in some cases

And like @Kayaman said:

> It's just an opinion. One reason I could guess is to make a distinction between Spring and J2EE ecosystems.